# Get specific row from dataset in rdlc expression

Tags: sql, rdlc, rdl

My data set like as.

```
 AccName    Debit   Credit
 A          500000  0
 B          400000  0
 C          30000   0
 D          10000   0
 E          0       950000
```

Now i want to show **AccName** i.e **E** in a Text box(which Credit greater than 0).DataSet contain only one row which contain Credit greater than 0.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a where condition  for filter the rows based on AccName column content

```
 select AccName,    Debit,   Credit
 from my_table 
 where AccName  = 'E';
```

or based on Credit column content

```
 select AccName,    Debit,   Credit
 from my_table 
 where Credit> 0;
```

If you need only AccName  then  select only this column

```
 select AccName
 from my_table 
 where Credit> 0;
```

Comment: I want to show AccName in textbox only credit>0 and tablix  will show all rows. @scaisEdge